# R, optimisation

Tags: r, optimization

I am trying to define an optimization problem. 
I got a function that generates my matrix of interest:

```
total_nutrition=function(x){averaging(cleaned_database(importation_year(x)))}
```

Then using the second column of this matrix, I want to generate an optimization problem:

```
objective = function(nutri_values, x) {sum( abs(nutri_values[,2]-x))}
objective2 = function(nutri_values,x) {sum( (nutri_values[,2]-x)^2)}
constraint1= function(nutri_values,x) {sum( (nutri_values[,2]-x)^2)-1}

objective_4=function(nutri_values){
initial_value=95
min4=auglag(initial_value, objective, heq=constraint1(nutri_values,x))
return(min4)
}
```

but when i try my function with

```
objective_4(total_nutrition(3))
```

i got the following error message (total_nutrition works perfectly)

```
Error in constraint1(nutri_values) : argument "x" is missing, with no default
```

any ideas?

Comment: You are calling `constraint1(nutri_values, x)` from within `objective_4`, but `x` there is not defined. You probably want to pass it as an argument to `objective_4`. And welcome to SO. :)

Comment: I still got the same error message...     Moreover I want to optimize x, isn t it weird to put it as an argument of the function

    objective_4=function(nutri_values,x){
    initial_value=95
    min4=auglag(initial_value, objective,     heq=constraint1(nutri_values,x))
    return(min4)
    }
    objective_4(total_nutrition(3))

Comment: Now you are calling `objective_4` with just one argument (`nutri_values`) whereas you have defined it for two (`nutri_values, x`). Use the following: `objective_4(total_nutrition(3), 3)`. Or `x <- 3; objective_4(total_nutrition(x), x)`.

Comment: I got the same error message. and also, i am quite reluctant to put two arguments as indeed in fact i got only one, and that x is the variable that is going to be optimized.

I will try to be clearer, i want to define a function which argument is a matrix, and which output is the argmin value of a certain function. of course the constraint are defined relatively to the argument matrix. Do you see what i mean? for example

    objective_1=function(nutri_values){
    min1=optimize(function(x)sum(abs(nutri_values[,2]-x)), ,lower = 30, upper = 120)
    return(min1$minimum)
    }